# Unity temporizador com scenemanager

Tags: c#, script, unity3d, unity-5

Basicamente é o seguinte: Eu tenho 2 códigos, 1 que serve para resetar o nível quando eu atiro a bola:

```
public Player player;
public float resetTimer = 5f;

void Update () {
        if (player.holdingBall == false) {
            resetTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
            if (resetTimer <= 0) {
                SceneManager.LoadScene ("Game");
            }
```

E este aqui que é um temporizador que vai para uma tela de fim de jogo

```
void Start () 
 {
  timerSeconds = GetComponent<Text> ();
 }
 
 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update () 
 {
  timer -= Time.deltaTime;
  timerSeconds.text = timer.ToString("f0");
  if (timer <= 0) 
  {
   Application.LoadLevel (LevelToLoad);
  }
 }
```

O problema é o seguinte: quando atiro a bola depois dos 5 segundos o nível reseta mas o temporizador também volta aos 30 e não queria que voltas-se.
Como faço? Devia ter juntado os dois ou...

Answer (score 0):

Basta tornar o timer que você não quer que resete um *static*

```
public static float timer = 30;
```

Ele não aparecerá mais no inspetor na Unity, mas funcionará como você está pedindo. Quando quiser reseta-lo, basta dar a ele um novo valor através de código, como timer = 30;